# kafka streams - number of open file descriptors keeps going up

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

Our kafka streaming app keeps opening new file descriptors as long as they are new incoming messages without ever closing old ones. It eventually leads to exception. We've raised the limit of open fds to 65k but it doesn't seem to help.

Both Kafka broker and Kafka streams library is version 2.1

The error message that keeps showing up in the logs is:

> org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run
>   StreamThread.java: 747
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop
>   StreamThread.java: 777
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce
>   StreamThread.java: 883
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit
>   StreamThread.java: 1029
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.commitAll
>   TaskManager.java: 405
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.commit
>   AssignedTasks.java: 346
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit
>   StreamTask.java: 431
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit
>   StreamTask.java: 443
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState
>   StreamTask.java: 491
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState
>   AbstractTask.java: 204
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush
>   ProcessorStateManager.java: 217
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.flush
>   MeteredKeyValueStore.java: 226
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore$AbstractStateStore.flush
>   WrappedStateStore.java: 85
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flush
>   RocksDBStore.java: 388
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flushInternal
>   RocksDBStore.java: 395 org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush RocksDB.java: 1743
>   org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush RocksDB.java org.rocksdb.RocksDBException:
>   While open a file for appending:
>   /tmp/kafka-streams/s4l-notifications-test/5_1/rocksdb/main-store/002052.sst:
>   Too many open files status: #object[org.rocksdb.Status 0x1cca4c5c
>   "org.rocksdb.Status@1cca4c5c"]
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while
>   executing flush from store main-store

Any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: Do you use iterators overs stores? Maybe you forget to close them leaking resources?

Comment: That was exactly the issue! We've missed that in documentation ...